# Too many columns specified: expected 2 and found 1

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Trying to output a graph from my data set but keep getting the ParserError as stated in the title I've checked similar questions on here but can't find one that is the same as my issue and can't see the issue with my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('usraa000000.0001', names=['colA','colB'], usecols=[2,504])

x = df['colA']
y = df['colB']

plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.show()
```

I'm really stuck for what the issue is here. The data folder is 4 columns of data. Decreasing the 'usecols' doesn't have any effect either.

Sorry if I'm being stupid I'm just really lost here.

Comment: usecols uses the names of the columns of your csv, eg 'colA' and not the number of rows. I think there is your issue.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Now I just need to work out why its outputting rows and not columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using usecols isn't correct, thus you are facing the issue.

> usecols is used for the name of your columns, eg ['colA','colB']

If you would like to define the rows which you are going to use, you can achieve it using iloc, based on the following examples:

```
data.iloc[0:5] # first five rows of dataframe
data.iloc[:, 0:2] # first two columns of data frame with all rows
data.iloc[[0,3,6,24], [0,5,6]] # 1st, 4th, 7th, 25th row + 1st 6th 7th columns.
data.iloc[0:5, 5:8] #first 5 rows and 5th, 6th, 7th columns of data frame
```

You can also give a read to these two resources [1](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/) [2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

EDIT:

```
dfA = pd.read_csv('usraa000000.0001', usecols=['colA'])
dfB = pd.read_csv('usraa000000.0001', usecols=['colB'])
x = dfA.iloc[2:504].tolist()
y = dfB.iloc[2:504].tolist()

plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it's saying that the ':' is invalid syntax.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide a snippet of your code?

Comment: Hi my issue has been sorted is there anyway for me to set this post as answered or something similar?

Comment: There is a [checkmark next to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that you can tick to accept it.